# Kubernetes probe events not visible but failing

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm using K8S `1.14` and Helm `3.3.1`.

I have an app which **works when deployed without probes**. Then I set two trivial probes:

```yaml
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - ls
                - /mnt
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5

          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - ls
                - /mnt
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
```

When I deploy via `helm upgrade`, the command eventually (~5 mins) fails with:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: release my-app failed, and has been rolled back due to atomic being set: timed out waiting for the condition
```

But in the events log there is no trace of any probe:

```
5m21s       Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/my-app     Scaled up replica set my-app-7 to 1
5m21s       Normal    Scheduled                 pod/my-app-7-6        Successfully assigned default/my-app-7-6 to gke-foo-testing-foo-testing-node-po-111-r0cu
5m21s       Normal    LoadBalancerNegNotReady   pod/my-app-7-6        Waiting for pod to become healthy in at least one of the NEG(s): [k8s1-222-default-my-app-80-54]
5m21s       Normal    SuccessfulCreate          replicaset/my-app-7   Created pod: my-app-7-6
5m20s       Normal    Pulling                   pod/my-app-7-6        Pulling image "my-registry/my-app:v0.1"
5m20s       Normal    Pulled                    pod/my-app-7-6        Successfully pulled image "my-registry/my-app:v0.1"
5m20s       Normal    Created                   pod/my-app-7-6        Created container my-app
5m20s       Normal    Started                   pod/my-app-7-6        Started container my-app
5m15s       Normal    Attach                    service/my-app        Attach 1 network endpoint(s) (NEG "k8s1-222-default-my-app-80-54" in zone "europe-west3-a")
19s         Normal    ScalingReplicaSet         deployment/my-app     Scaled down replica set my-app-7 to 0
19s         Normal    SuccessfulDelete          replicaset/my-app-7   Deleted pod: my-app-7-6
19s         Normal    Killing                   pod/my-app-7-6        Stopping container my-app
```

Hence the question: what are the probes doing and where?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue or you managed to fix it with the answers provided?

Comment: still stuck here. I'm going to try in the afternoon with a different environment which uses a different k8s version (1.17) and will update it here.

Comment: @pietro909 I think is the better approach, since helm `3.3.x` only [supports](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/version_skew/#:~:text=2%20client%2C%20so%20it%20is,n%2D1%20versions%20of%20Kubernetes.) `1.18.x - 1.15.x` k8s version

Comment: I've got it "working" by removing basic-auth from the Express server running in the service. Which doesn't make sense since the probe is not an http one -_- and I still need basic auth.

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced the same scenario here and everything went fine. The release was deployed and the pod is running. Did you check within the container if the `/mnt` really exists?

```
      Events:
      Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
      ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
      Normal  Scheduled  3m41s                     Successfully assigned default/nginx-deployment2-5cdd568667-blsc7 to minikube
      Normal  Pulling    3m41s  kubelet, minikube  Pulling image "nginx"
      Normal  Pulled     3m38s  kubelet, minikube  Successfully pulled image "nginx" in 2.769840982s
      Normal  Created    3m38s  kubelet, minikube  Created container nginx
      Normal  Started    3m38s  kubelet, minikube  Started container nginx


    NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    nginx-deployment2-5cdd568667-blsc7   1/1     Running   0          4m59s
```

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: nginx-deployment2
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: ameba
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: ameba
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nginx
            image: nginx
            ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              name: nginx-port
            livenessProbe:
              exec:
                command:
                  - ls
                  - /mnt
              initialDelaySeconds: 5
              periodSeconds: 5
    
            readinessProbe:
              exec:
                command:
                  - ls
                  - /mnt
              initialDelaySeconds: 5
              periodSeconds: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the helm then re-apply it again: `helm del --purge <APPNAME>`
Also which helm version are you using? Try upgrading to `v3.2.1`, there's an open issue that tries to fix this incident with previously failed upgrades: https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/5939

Comment: I'm using K8S `1.14` and Helm `3.3.1`.

Unfortunately, is not an issue with failed upgrades: I can still re-deploy by just commenting out the probes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't if you image include bash, but if you just want to verify if the directory exists, you can do the samething using others shell commands, try this:

```
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - -c
                - ls /mnt
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5

          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - -c
                - ls /mnt
            initialDelaySeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
```

In bash you can also try to use the `test` built-in function:

`[[ -d /mnt ]]` = The `-d` verify if the directory `/mnt` exists.

As an alternative, there is also the command `stat`:

`stat /mnt`

If you want to check if the directory has any specific file, use the complete path with filename include.